# Problem with the numeration appearing in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, page-numbering

I have some trouble with the page numbers printed in the table of contents. I am writing a text in book class. In my text, I first print a table of contents with the commands

```
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
```

Since I wanted to add a list of figures and a list of tables that would appear in the table of contents, I wrote the following commands.

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables
```

The list of figures is on page v and the list of tables is on page vii. However, they appear in the table of contents as being on pages iii and vi respectively (which makes really no sense because the tables are at distance 2 and not 3). I tried to compile several times to see if the problem would fix itself but it does not.

Is there a mistake in my line codes? Or is it a known bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first `\addcontentsline` is executed immediately after the the end of the ToC's contents; only then `\listoffigures` adds a page break (or, in the case of `book`' s default `twoside` option, a break to the next odd page). Solution: add `\cleardoublepage` before `\addcontentsline`.

```
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables
```

Answer (score 5):

Check out [the `tocbibind` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind). It will automatically add things like lists of figures to the table of contents.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me. How do I change page numbering from the footer to the header right corner for the table of content, list of tables and listoffigures?