# How to get correct page number of index in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, indexing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with the numeration appearing in the table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17078/problem-with-the-numeration-appearing-in-the-table-of-contents)
>   [Index is incorrectly listed in the table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31535/index-is-incorrectly-listed-in-the-table-of-contents)

I am using

```
\usepackage{madeidx}
\makeindex
```

I added entry of index in ToC with

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\printindex
```

This way I can get entry of Index in ToC, how ever page number it is printing is one less than actual page number.

How to get correct page number?

Answer (score 6):

**Solution I:** Prepend `\addcontentsline` with `\clearpage` (or `\cleardoublepage` in twoside and openright):

```
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\printindex
```

**Solution II:** Use the [`tocbibind`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind) package that manages automatic inclusion of Table of Contents, Index, Bibliography, ... into the Table of Contents. The package behaviour can be controlled by some parameters, see the documentation at the link above.

Comment: tocbibind produces right page number in toc, but it links Index to the previous chapter.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin The package has `[chapter]` option that solves this issue.

Comment: \usepackage[chapter]{tocbibind} did not work for me

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to your document preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\theindex}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}}
\makeatother
```

This inserts your contents-related entry as part of the last things before the index is actually printed.

Comment: It gives wrong page number and makes link to the last chapter before Index.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin: I get the correct page number when using a small MWE. If you're using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), you should add `\phantomsection` before `\addcontentsline`.